# Is it possible to create spring beans in a cycle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have a class

```
@Data
public class SingleMan implements Man {

    private final MegaMan megaman;

    public SingleMan(String name) {
        MegaMan man = new MegaMan();
        man.setName(name);
        this.megaman = man;
    }

    @Override
    public MegaMan getMega() {
        return megaman;
    }
}
```

And I have a lot of different names, for example: John, Mike, Alisa.
I want to initialize 3 beans of SingleManConfiguration in spring configuration file.
A can do it this way.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Man john() {
        return new SingleMan("John");
    }

    @Bean
    public Man mike() {
        return new SingleMan("Mike");
    }

    @Bean
    public Man alisa() {
        return new SingleMan("Alisa");
    }
}
```

But I want to somehow make it in a for cycle.
I want to do something like this.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    List<String> names = List.of("Mike", "John", "Alisa");

    //and here somehow initialize 3 beans (not a list that will be bean)    

}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Please rephrase.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have a list of names and I want to iterate through it creating spring beans (using these names).

Comment: You probably want a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is it the only way?

Comment: Anything that has access to the `BeanFactory`, so you can register bean definitions dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DefaultListableBeanFactory` to initialize and register your custom beans dynamically:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE;

@Component("beanInitializer")
public class BeanInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private DefaultListableBeanFactory factory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createBeans() {
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Mike", "John", "Alisa");
        for (String name: names) {
            Object initialized = factory.initializeBean(new SingleMan(name), name);
            factory.autowireBeanProperties(initialized, AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
            factory.registerSingleton(name, initialized);
        }
    }

}
```

You can later autowire your custom beans, just make sure you use `@DependsOn` to wait until `BeanInitializer` creates them:

```
@Component
@DependsOn("beanInitializer")
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private Collection<SingleMan> beans;

    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(beans);
    }
}
```